# Word meaning vulnerable to the elements

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to see what is the closest word I can get that means vulnerable to the elements. One word is preferred, as opposed to a phrase. Here is a basic example:

> Steel is ____________, but titanium is not ____________.

Ideally the word is not only relevant to corrosion like in the above example, but also other elements, whatever they may be (sunlight, wind, cold, ect)

> Chemlights are ____________, but flashlights are not ____________.

(in the 2nd example the element implied is sunlight. Sunlight will degrade the chemlight, but will not impact the flashlight's performance -- not that you would use a flashlight on a sunny day, assumed you used at a later date at night after exposure to sunlight)

Comment: *Impervious*, meaning *incapable of being damaged*, might do, but it's an anotonym of the phrase "vulnerable to the elements".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you be looking for [pervious and impervious](https://wikidiff.com/pervious/impervious)?

> As adjectives the difference between pervious and impervious is that pervious is admitting passage; capable of being penetrated by another body or substance; permeable while impervious is unaffected or unable to be affected by.

or simply

[Weatherproof](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/weatherproof)

> Resistant to the effects of bad weather, especially rain.

Comment: I think he's looking for one word which is the exact opposite of weatherproof, like a better word than weather-pervious.

Answer (score 1):

*susceptible* works, although that doesn't exclusively refer to susceptibility to the elements.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/susceptible):

> susceptible - adjective - sus·cep·ti·ble  \ sə-ˈsep-tə-bəl \ - 1 : capable of submitting to an action,
> process, or operation a theory susceptible to proof
>
> 2 : open, subject, or unresistant to some stimulus, influence, or
> agency susceptible to pneumonia
>
> 3 : impressionable, responsive a susceptible mind
>
> — susceptibleness noun
>
> — susceptibly adverb

Comment: The word you suggest is a good choice, but to make it easier for the person who posted the question to see why it's relevant, please consider adding a dictionary definition of _susceptible_ in the relevant sense (together with a citation to the dictionary you used) and consider explaining why it is relevant.